# Fade in and Fade out links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, fadein, fadeout, jquery-hover

Please could anyone help me in this simple script...

```
<script>
$(".offr-list-desc-anch").hide();
$(function () {
    $(".grey-shadow").hover(function () {
        $(".offr-list-desc-anch").stop().fadeIn()
    }, function () {
        $(".offr-list-desc-anch").stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```

I use this to fade in and out my links but when I hover one link, the effect happens to all other links... I just want to take effect only on the hovered link..

this is my HTML

```
<a href="#" class="offr-list-itm grey-shadow">
    <div class="offr-list-desc-txt"> 
    <img width="223" height="159" border="0" class="grey-shadow" src="images/sportive_suit.jpg">
      <div class="offr-list-desc-anch" >
        <div class="offr-list-item-detls">
          <div class="price"><span class="price-value">200</span><span>LE</span></div>
          <div class="discount-box">
            <div class="off"><span class="price-detalis-tit">Discount</span> <span class="save-currency">50 <span class="save-currency-symbol">%</span> </span> </div>
            <div class="save"> <span class="price-detalis-tit">You Save</span> <span class="save-currency"> 200 <span class="save-currency-symbol"> LE </span></span> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="more-offers-unitit"> L.E 200 Instead of L.E 400 for 1 Month of Self Defense Classes from Circle Aikido</p>
      </div>
   <script>
  $(".offr-list-desc-anch").hide();
  $(function(){
      $(".grey-shadow").stop().hover(function(){

          $(".offr-list-desc-anch").fadeIn()
          },function(){$(".offr-list-desc-anch").stop().fadeOut();
              });

              return false;

      });
  </script>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: How does your html look like? You need to target specific one.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle so we can find the error?

Comment: there is an anchor tag but I don't know why it did not appear in code here

Comment: grey-shadow is the anchor tag that effect would happen when it gets hovered...

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry See the answer updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the target which is specific to the current hovered element so that it doesn't impact other elements. So try this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".offr-list-desc-anch").hide();
    $(".grey-shadow").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".offr-list-desc-anch").stop().fadeToggle(); //find the element specific to hovered anchor tag element
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsC5L/)**

Also do not wrap the scripts inside the div element, you don't need to do that.

Comment: I don't think `find` will work as the list is not inside the `img` tag

Comment: Oh thank you so much... it is working very good now..

but I still can't see where I did wrong..

Yes I know that I have to specify the target that I need to make action on... but where/how you did it in your script??

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry do you see `$(this).find()` it selects only the element specific to the one hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".grey-shadow").hover(function () {
  $(this).next().stop().fadeIn()
}, function () {
  $(this).next().stop().fadeOut();
});
```

The idea is to use your hover point as the reference not the entire DOM.

Comment: yes but it would not work that way because my hovered point is not the next or the previous to the div I want to make effect on..